# Verifying divergence theorem for the intersection of a paraboloid and a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

trying to verify divergence theorem on the region R bounded by the paraboloid z=x^2+y^2 and the plane x+y+z=1. I was given the hint that I wouldn't necessarily need to find the explicit parametrization for R (I was recommended to just find the volume of R by considering the vertical projection of R onto the xy plane). I don't see how this helps... specifically, wouldn't I still need to parametrize the surfaces for the surface integral? And how would I go about computing the volume integral? Like what bounds should I use? Sorry, just so confused here.

Comment: Where's the vector field?

Comment: The vector field is F<x,y,z>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Volume of region between paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ and plane $z=1-x-y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462200/volume-of-region-between-paraboloid-z-x2y2-and-plane-z-1-x-y)