# Volume of region between paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ and plane $z=1-x-y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having a lot of difficulty... I need to find the volume of the region bounded by the plane $z=1-x-y$ and the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$. Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of the plane and the paraboloid is a circle
$\left(x+\frac12\right)^2 + \left(y+\frac12\right)^2=\frac32$. Apply the variable change $u = x+\frac12$ and $v=y+\frac12$ to center the circle at origin $u^2+v^2=\frac32$. The plane becomes $z_1=2-u-v$, and the paraboloid $z_2=\left(u-\frac12\right)^2 + \left(v-\frac12\right)^2$. Then, set up the volume integral as,

$$V=\int_{u^2+v^2\le\frac32}(z_1-z_2)dudv=\int_{u^2+v^2\le\frac32}\left(\frac32-u^2-v^2\right)dudv$$

Perform the integral in the cylindrical coordinates,

$$V=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac32}}\left(\frac32-r^2\right)rdr=\frac{9\pi}{8}$$

Comment: Ahhh got it... thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You already have an answer showing how to develop an integral for this volume. It does not require much knowledge of quadratic surfaces, just the ability to solve the integral when you get it.

Here is a somewhat different approach. The volume is the integral of the difference of the two formulas for $z,$ integrated over the region in the $x,y$ plane where the given plane is above the paraboloid.

The difference of a plane and a paraboloid is another paraboloid.
To see which paraboloid, take the difference between $1 - x - y$ (height of the plane at any point) and $x^2 + y^2$ (height of the paraboloid):

$$ (1 - x - y) - (x^2 + y^2) = - x^2 - y^2 - x - y + 1. $$

Now complete the squares. The idea is we want all the $x$ and $y$ terms to be accounted for by two terms of the form $a(x-b)^2$ and $c(y-d)^2.$
We're willing to regroup constant terms in order to make this work.
For the $x$ terms we have $-x^2 - x,$ which is almost $-\left(x+\frac12\right)^2$
except for a constant term:

$$ -\left(x+\frac12\right)^2 = -\left(x^2 + x + \frac14\right)
 = -x^2 - x -\frac14. $$

Similarly, $ -\left(y+\frac12\right)^2 = -y^2 - y -\frac14. $
So if we add the two squared terms we just found, we get

$$ -\left(x+\frac12\right)^2 - \left(y+\frac12\right)^2
= - x^2 - y^2 - x - y - \frac12. $$

But we need $+1$ instead of $-\frac12,$ so we add 
$1 - \left(-\frac12\right) = \frac32$ to make up the difference:

$$ -\left(x+\frac12\right)^2 - \left(y+\frac12\right)^2 + \frac32
= - x^2 - y^2 - x - y + 1. $$

So that's a downward-opening paraboloid with its axis of symmetry at 
$(x,y) = \left(-\frac12,-\frac12\right).$
We want to integrate this over the region in the $x,y$ plane where the value of
$z = -\left(x+\frac12\right)^2 - \left(y+\frac12\right)^2 + \frac32$ is positive, which is the interior of a circle with center at 
$(x,y) = \left(-\frac12,-\frac12\right).$

But we can simplify this further. Translate the new paraboloid $\frac12$ unit in the $x$ direction and in the $y$ direction so that we move its axis to $(x,y)=(0,0).$
The formula for the translated paraboloid is

$$z = -x^2 - y^2 + \frac32,$$

which we integrate over a circle centered at $(x,y)=(0,0),$
and the radius of the circle is $\sqrt{\frac32}.$

If you convert to polar coordinates the formula of the paraboloid becomes
$$ z = -r^2 + \frac32$$
for $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{\frac32}$ and any angle $\theta,$ so the integral is

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{3/2}} \left(-r^2 + \frac32\right)
 r \,\mathrm dr \,\mathrm d\theta.$$

To get to this point takes some thinking (using experience or inspired guesswork),
but the integral itself is relatively easy to solve.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

We first find the region that we will integrate over. It is the projection of the curve which is the intersection of the two surfaces: $z = 1 - x - y, z = x^2+y^2$. Thus $1-x-y-x^2-y^2 = 0\implies (x+\frac{1}{2})^2+(y+\frac{1}{2})^2= \frac{3}{2}$ which is the circle centered at $(-\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2})$ and having radius $r = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ on the $xy$ plane. Thus the set up for the volume is: $V = \displaystyle \int_{-\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}^{-\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}} \displaystyle \int_{-\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}-(y+\frac{1}{2})^2}}^{-\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}-(y+\frac{1}{2})^2}} (1-x-y-x^2-y^2)dxdy$.